# Create [more than one] button that says "show next in [this category]" for different fields

Tags: javascript

I have a page that I'm going to fill with snippets that are each in its own `div class="filterDiv" data-category="all thiscategory thatcategory anothercategory"`.

The categories are all/should all be part of larger categories (eg `"europecat"` is under "Locations", and `"physicscat"` is under... "Big Tag", for now.

The reason they're in `data-category` and not just part of the class is that I copied code that filters the `filterDiv` entries that are in `div class="container"` using checkboxes that are placed inside `div id="categoryBoxes"` - that's why there's animals, cars, colors in the JS script (it still works for any category, though).

What I want to do is also have `prev` and `next` buttons *inside* each `filterDiv`, but have those buttons send you to the previous or next entry *in each category*.

The Javascript in my snippet looks overwhelming but it's complete and functional, I just don't know what to add to it to make prev and next buttons for each category.

```js
// If we save our current state somewhere, we can easily filter the divs.
var checkedCategories = ["cars", "animals", "fruits", "colors"];

// We need a function that detects the click on a checkbox and adds/removes that category.
var changeCategory = function changeCategory(event) {
  // The event object will tell us exactly what was clicked.
  var checkbox = event.target;
  // The category we want toa dd or remove is the attribute
  var category = checkbox.getAttribute("data-category");
  // To check if we already have the category in the array, we just check the index.
  var savedCategoryIndex = checkedCategories.indexOf(category);
  // If the checkbox is checked, that category has to already exist in the array or get added. if it is not checked and is present in the array, it needs to be removed.
  if (checkbox.checked && savedCategoryIndex === -1) {
    checkedCategories.push(category);
  } else if (!checkbox.checked && savedCategoryIndex !== -1) {
    checkedCategories.splice(savedCategoryIndex, 1);
  }

  renderCategories();
};

// We want a reusable function that will show/hide any categories we want to see.
var renderCategories = function renderCategories() {
  // We need a list of all the divs. So we just select all the divs that have the data-category attribute and slice them into an array.
  // Could be replaced by Array.from() if your browser supports it.
  var categoryDivs = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("div[data-category]"));
  // Now we need to loop over all the divs and check if they need to get hidden or not.
  categoryDivs.forEach(function(div) {
    // Get all the tags the div has
    var tags = div.getAttribute("data-category").split(" ");
    // If at least one tag of the div is inside our categories array, we know it'll need to get shown.
    var divShouldBeShown = tags.some(function(tag) {
      return checkedCategories.indexOf(tag) !== -1;
    });
    // The decide if we need to hide the div or not.
    // Can be replaced by a classList.toggle() if your browser supports it.
    if (divShouldBeShown && div.className.indexOf("hidden") !== -1) {
      div.className = div.className.replace("hidden", "");
    } else if (!divShouldBeShown && div.className.indexOf("hidden") === -1) {
      div.className = div.className + " hidden";
    }
  });
};
// Finally we have to add an event to the checkboxes.
document.querySelector("#categoryBoxes").addEventListener('click', changeCategory);
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.filterDivcontainer {
  margin-top: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.filterDiv {
  display: block;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

body {
  background: #f5f5f5;
}

mark {
  background-color: #fff2cc;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}

th {
  background-color: #333;
  color: white;
}

img {
  border: solid 3px white;
  margin: 5px
}
```

```html
<div id="categoryBoxes">
  <div style="float: right;"><input type="checkbox" data-category="all" name="category" unchecked>See All</div>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <h3>Locations</h3>
      </th>
      <th>
        <h3>Type</h3>
      </th>
      <th>
        <h3>Big Tag</h3>
      </th>
      <th>
        <h3>Little Tag</h3>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <!-- Locations -->
        <!-- Big Locs -->
        <input type="checkbox" data-category="northam" name="category" unchecked>North America<br>
        <input type="checkbox" data-category="southam" name="category" unchecked>South America<br>
        <input type="checkbox" data-category="europecat" name="category" unchecked>Europe<br> and the rest coming
      </td>

      <td>
        <!-- type -->
      </td>

      <td>
        <!-- big tag -->
        <input type="checkbox" data-category="mathstat" name="category" unchecked>Math & Statistics<br>
        <input type="checkbox" data-category="microbiocat" name="category" unchecked>Microbiology<br>
        <input type="checkbox" data-category="physicscat" name="category" unchecked>Physics<br>
      </td>

      <td>
        <!-- little tag -->
        <input type="checkbox" data-category="compasscat" name="category" unchecked>The Compass<br>
        <input type="checkbox" data-category="meancat" name="category" unchecked>The Mean<br>
        <input type="checkbox" data-category="microscopecat" name="category" unchecked>The Microscope<br>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<hr>

<div class="container">

  <div class="filterDiv" data-category="all europecat mathstat physicscat compasscat meancat">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Locations</th>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Big Tag</th>
        <th>Little Tag</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>← Europe →</td>
        <td>← →</td>
        <td>← Math & Statistics →<br>← Physics →</td>
        <td>← The Compass →<br>← The Mean →</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <img width="30%" style="float: right;" src="https://m2.dalvey.com/media/magefan_blog/history-of-the-compass-navigation-hero2.jpg"> By the year 1500, the magnetic compass or “needle” was firmly established as a basic tool of increasingly adventurous
    mariners. By 1500 it was well known that the difference between true and magnetic north varied from place to place, often by considerable amounts—10° or more to the east or to the west. It was at that time believed this was due to the lack of magnetic
    attraction by the sea and the consequent bias in the needle toward landmasses and away from seas. <mark>The correction needed to find true north from a compass was called <i>the variation of the needle</i>.</mark>
    <div class="source">Source: <cite>The Seven Pillars of Statistical Wisdom</cite> by Stephen M Stigler</div>
    <hr>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've done some searching but I'm little too inexperienced to be able to modify code so it works with what I already have. Is that okay?